# Iterating a file to find string and output information

Tags: python, iteration

I am trying to print out certain information from a file. I have a file that I am trying to iterate over on each line to set as a variable and print certain output if that string is found.

The file I am iterating is called "agent" and contains two IP addresses.

The file I am searching to find if the IP address exists in that file is called "snaps".

Here is my code:

```
for agn in iter(open('agent')):
    for line in open('snaps'):
        if agn in line:
            print line.strip()
```

When I run the script it does not error out. It just does not print anything. What it should print is the following:

```
10.0.69.184@1403769709
10.0.69.184@1403775680
10.0.69.152@1403632141
10.0.69.152@1403714562
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how you files looks like, but I think you may want to change your nested-loop solution to:

```
with open('agent') as f1:
    for agn in f1:
        with open('snaps') as f2:
            for line in f2:
                if agn in line:
                    print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

If it only contains two IP addresses, read the file first into a list, then search in that list while reading the second file, like this:

```
with open('agent.txt') as f:
    ip_addresses = list(i.rstrip() for i in f)

with open('snaps.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split('@')[0] in ip_addresses:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it.

```
for agn in iter(open('agent')):
    for line in open('snaps'):
            if str(agn).strip() in line:
                    print line.strip()
```

Thank you for the suggestions though. Much appreciated.